# Animaciones velocidades

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una animación simple con `html` + `CSS` + `Js`, y no consigo que las velocidades sean iguales en todos los navegadores y que funcionen:

- En Chrome no me funciona el cambio de velocidad, parece que todos son velocidad normal
- Firefox sólo parece cambiarme a velocidad rápida, y cuando cambio de velocidad el  sol cambia de lugar

Según los manuales, para que sean iguales en todos los manuales sólo hay que añadir:

```
@-moz-keyframes 
@-webkit-keyframes
```

Los he añadido con los mismos parámetros que `@keyframes` sol pero aún así no puedo.

Espero vuestra ayuda.

Código HTML:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  cuadro = document.getElementById("sol");
}

function parar() {
  cuadro.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  cuadro.style.MozAnimationPlayState = "paused";
  cuadro.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
}

function seguir() {
  cuadro.style.animationPlayState = "running";
  cuadro.style.MozAnimationPlayState = "running";
  cuadro.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
}

function velocidad(num) {
  valor = num + "s";
  cuadro.style.animationDuration = valor;
  cuadro.style.MozAnimationDuration = valor;
  cuadro.style.WebkitAnimationDuration = valor;
}
```

```css
.sol {
  background: #FFA500;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -110px;
  top: 30%;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 140, 0, 0.5);
  animation-name: sol;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: sol;
  -moz-animation-duration: 20s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: sol;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes sol {
  0% {
    left: -110px;
    top: 30%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 50%;
    top: 5%;
    background: #FF4500;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(100% + 10px);
    top: 30%;
    background: #bee2e6;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(73, 92, 95, 0.5);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes sol {
  0% {
    left: -110px;
    top: 30%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 50%;
    top: 5%;
    background: #FF4500;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(100% + 10px);
    top: 30%;
    background: #bee2e6;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(73, 92, 95, 0.5);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes sol {
  0% {
    left: -110px;
    top: 30%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 50%;
    top: 5%;
    background: #FF4500;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(100% + 10px);
    top: 30%;
    background: #bee2e6;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(73, 92, 95, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="recuadro1">
    <div class="fondo">
      <div class="boton">
        <p>
          <input type="button" name="stop" value="stop" onclick="parar()" />
          <input type="button" name=”play” value="play" onclick="seguir()" />
          <b>Elige la velocidad:</b>
          <select name="vel">
            <option selected="selected" onclick="velocidad(4)">Normal</option>
            <option onclick="velocidad(10)">Muy lento</option>
            <option onclick="velocidad(8)">Lento</option>
            <option onclick="velocidad(2)">Rápido</option>
            <option onclick="velocidad(1)">Muy Rápido</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="sol" id="sol"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="campamento"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Invierte el orden de  "@keyframes sol"  y  "animation-name: sol; animation-duration: 20s; animation-iteration-count: infinite;"   con respecto a los de firefox y chrome. Puede ser mera cuestión de prioridades