# Al seleccionar las distintas velocidades no coge el valor- JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una animación básica en *Js* en la que el sol pasa por el cielo, y debo poder pararlo, darle al play y cambiarle la velocidad.

Funciona el play y que se pare, pero no me funciona el cambio de velocidad.

```
    var cuadro = undefined;

    window.onload = function () {
    cuadro = document.getElementById("sol");}

    function parar() {
    cuadro.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    cuadro.style.MozAnimationPlayState = "paused";
    cuadro.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
    }

    function seguir() {
    cuadro.style.animationPlayState = "running";
    cuadro.style.MozAnimationPlayState = "running";
    cuadro.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";}

    function velocidad(num) {
    valor = num + "s";
    cuadro.style.animationDuration = valor;
    cuadro.style.MozAnimationDuration = valor;
    cuadro.style.WebkitAnimationDuration = valor;
    }
```

Cambio la velocidad con este select:

```
<select name="vel">
    <option selected="selected" onclick="velocidad(4)">Normal</option>
    <option onclick="velocidad(10)">Muy lento</option>
    <option onclick="velocidad(8)">Lento</option>
    <option onclick="velocidad(2)">Rápido</option>
    <option onclick="velocidad(1)">Muy Rápido</option>
</select>
```

Y el start y stop:

```
<input type="button" name="stop" value="stop" onclick="parar()"/>
<input type="button" name=”play” value="play" onclick="seguir()"/>
```

El problema es que cuando selecciono alguna de las velocidades, el valor no cambia.

Comment: tienes valor en comillas cuadro.style.animationDuration = "valor", cuando asignes una variable va sin comillas.

Comment: Por lo que dice Jordi Baliellas Portet, creo que sería cuadro.style.animationDuration = num + "s";

Comment: he quitado las comillas en valor y aún así sigo teniendo el mismo problema (lo he editado aquí tb)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Animaciones velocidades](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323639/animaciones-velocidades)

Comment: Hola Rosi, bienvenida a la comunidad. No está bien visto duplicar preguntas. Te recomiendo eliminar una, la que tu consideres pertinente. Si deseas que tu pregunta tenga más atención, puedes ofrecer una recompensa. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el `<option>` no detecta los clicks.

tendrás que en el select poner onchange y llamar a la función de velocidad:

```
<select name="vel" onchange="velocidad(event)">
    <option selected="selected" value="4">Normal</option>
    <option value="10">Muy lento</option>
    <option value="8">Lento</option>
    <option value="2">Rápido</option>
    <option value="1">Muy Rápido</option>
</select>
```

y en la función pillar el value del valor seleccionado:

```
function velocidad(event) {
    valor = event.target.value + "s";
    cuadro.style.animationDuration = valor;
    cuadro.style.MozAnimationDuration = valor;
    cuadro.style.WebkitAnimationDuration = valor;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jordi! has dado en el clavo ;)